# R: Using fitdistrplus to fit curve over histogram of discrete data

Tags: r, statistics, fitdistrplus

So I have this discrete set of data `my_dat` that I am trying to fit a curve over to be able to generate random variables based on `my_dat`.  I had great success using `fitdistrplus` on continuous data but have many errors when attempting to use it for discrete data.

Table settings:

```
library(fitdistrplus)

my_dat <- c(2,5,3,3,3,1,1,2,4,6,
            3,2,2,8,3,4,3,3,4,4,
            2,1,5,3,1,2,2,4,3,4,
            2,4,1,6,2,3,2,1,2,4,
            5,1,2,3,2)
```

I take a look at the histogram of the data first:

```
hist(my_dat)
```

[image: <code>hist(my_dat)</code>]

Since the data's discrete, I decide to try a binomial distribution or the negative binomial distribution to fit **and this is where I run into trouble**: Here I try to define each:

```
fitNB3 <- fitdist(my_dat, discrete = T, distr = "nbinom" ) #NaNs Produced
fitB3 <- fitdist(my_dat, discrete = T, distr = "binom")
```

I receive two errors:

1. `fitNB3` seems to run but notes that "NaNs Produced" - can anyone let me 
   know why this is the case?
2. `fitB3` doesn't run at all and provides me with the error:  "Error in start.arg.default(data10, distr = distname) :  Unknown starting values for distribution binom." - can anyone point out why this won't work here?  I am unclear about providing a starting number given that the data is discrete (I attempted to use `start = 1` in the `fitdist` function but I received another error:  "Error in fitdist(my_dat, discrete = T, distr = "binom", start = 1) : the function mle failed to estimate the parameters, with the error code 100"

I've been spinning my wheels for a while on this but I would be take any feedback regarding these errors.

Answer (score 2):

1. Don't use hist on discrete data, because it doesn't do what you think it's doing.

   Compare `plot(table(my_dat))` with `hist(my_dat)`... and then ponder how many wrong impressions you've gotten doing this before. If you *must* use `hist`, make sure you specify the breaks, don't rely on defaults designed for continuous variables.

   [image: Histogram and plot(table()) showing distinctly different appearance because hist is combining '1' and '2' into first bin]

   ```
    hist(my_dat)
    lines(table(my_dat),col=4,lwd=6,lend=1)
   ```
2. Neither of your models can be suitable as both these distributions start from 0, not 1, and with the size of values you have, p(0) will not be ignorably small.
3. I don't get any errors fitting the negative binomial when I run your code.
4. The issue you had with fitting the binomial is you need to supply starting values for the parameters, which are called `size` (n) and `prob` (p), so
   you'd need to say something like:

   ```
   fitdist(my_dat, distr = "binom", start=list(size=15, prob=0.2))
   ```

   *However*, you will then get a new problem! The optimizer assumes that the parameters are continuous and will fail on `size`.

   On the other hand this is probably a good thing because with unknown *n* MLE is not well behaved, particularly when *p* is small.

   Typically, with the binomial it would be expected that you know *n*. In that case, estimation of *p* could be done as follows:

   ```
   fitdist(my_dat, distr = "binom", fix.arg=list(size=20), start=list(prob=0.15))
   ```

   However, with fixed *n*, maximum likelihood estimation is straightforward in any case -- you don't need an optimizer for that.

   If you really don't know *n*, there are a number of better-behaved estimators than the MLE to be found, but that's outside the scope of this question.